# Splitting a set of rows, how can I deal with whitespace?

Tags: java, arrays, split, whitespace

For example, this is the data I am working with:

```
  1001    1   16.7     1.2       0   241.1   549.2
  1661    1   17.4     1.3       0   234.8   579.7
  1211    2            1.2       3   217.8   502.2
  1515    2   51.0     1.8       1    72.8   563.9
  1210    1   16.8     1.1       0    56.7   100.0
```

I loop through each row, storing it in line[] by using .split("\s+") using JAVA.

However, when reaching line 3, it doesn't recognise that there is data missing. How can I solve this? Instead, it creates an array length of 6 instead of 7 like the rest.

Thanks

Comment: Is this tab delimited data? If so, you can split on just a tab character.

Comment: Or don't split using `split(...)`. Since each data point has a defined character width, simply extract substrings and trim them, the key being for your code to follow the ["KISS" rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): "keep it simple, stupid". Good luck!

Comment: You could `split(" ")` and then use the resulting array to create a new array. Loop through it and take everything that doesn't equal a space. It's not efficient but....